# How to start local docker pulled image (apereo/cas)?

Tags: docker, cas

I tried to use:

```
docker pull apereo/cas
```

I then tried:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443 -d --name="cas" apereo/cas
```

I am getting the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"cas-overlay/bin/run-cas.sh\": stat cas-overlay/bin/run-cas.sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

There is no documentation besides docker pulling the image.

What can I do to get past this issue?

https://github.com/apereo/cas-webapp-docker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like someone goofed; the current `latest` tag is legit broken. Try a [different pinned tag](https://hub.docker.com/r/apereo/cas/tags/). `v.5.2.2` worked for me, like so:

`docker run -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443 -d --name="cas" apereo/cas:v5.2.2`

Comment: I have used this command and I am not able to access the interface or anything at the ports, can you please advise what might be the issue?

Comment: @Karan Run the container in interactive mode to see what's happening inside it. Maybe it is failing to start because of a missing certificate and you have to initialize the keystore. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52099768/run-apereo-cas-docker-image-prints-failed-to-start-connector-error