# Run "apereo/cas" docker image prints "Failed to start connector" error

Tags: spring, docker, tomcat, cas, catalina

My goal is to run CAS to replace ADFS. I thought starting with the docker image is a good place to begin.

I've tried running two different versions of `apereo/cas` and both have the same error.

Here's what I tried.

### command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 apereo/cas:v5.3.2
```

### output

```
   __   ____      _      ____   __
  / /  / ___|    / \    / ___|  \ \
 | |  | |       / _ \   \___ \   | |
 | |  | |___   / ___ \   ___) |  | |
 | |   \____| /_/   \_\ |____/   | |
  \_\                           /_/

CAS Version: 5.3.2
CAS Commit Id: 145d8c3dd5e27333dd05f5cc10987df4656fba5e
CAS Build Date/Time: 2018-07-30T21:09:46Z
Spring Boot Version: 1.5.14.RELEASE
Spring Version: 4.3.18.RELEASE
Java Home: /opt/zulu8.30.0.1-jdk8.0.172-linux_x64/jre
Java Vendor: Azul Systems, Inc.
Java Version: 1.8.0_172
JVM Free Memory: 24 MB
JVM Maximum Memory: 539 MB
JVM Total Memory: 52 MB
JCE Installed: Yes
Node Version: N/A
NPM Version: N/A
OS Architecture: amd64
OS Name: Linux
OS Version: 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs
OS Date/Time: 2018-08-30T13:18:59.269
OS Temp Directory: /tmp
------------------------------------------------------------
Apache Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
------------------------------------------------------------


2018-08-30 13:18:59,416 INFO [org.apereo.cas.configuration.DefaultCasConfigurationPropertiesSourceLocator] - <Configuration directory [/etc/cas/config] is not a directory or cannot be found at the specific path>
2018-08-30 13:18:59,470 INFO [org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration] - <Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='casCompositePropertySource', propertySources=[PropertiesPropertySource {name='embeddedYamlOverriddenProperties'}]]>
2018-08-30 13:18:59,500 INFO [org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication] - <The following profiles are active: standalone>
2018-08-30 13:18:59,674 INFO [org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplicationContext] - <Refreshing CasWebApplicationContext()>
2018-08-30 13:19:09,553 WARN [org.apereo.cas.config.CasCoreTicketsConfiguration] - <Runtime memory is used as the persistence storage for retrieving and managing tickets. Tickets that are issued during runtime will be LOST when the web server is restarted. This MAY impact SSO functionality.>
2018-08-30 13:19:09,557 INFO [org.apereo.cas.util.CoreTicketUtils] - <Ticket registry encryption/signing is turned off. This MAY NOT be safe in a clustered production environment. Consider using other choices to handle encryption, signing and verification of ticket registry tickets, and verify the chosen ticket registry does support this behavior.>
2018-08-30 13:19:36,081 INFO [org.apereo.cas.config.CasConfigurationSupportUtilitiesConfiguration] - <CAS is configured to NOT watch configuration directory [/etc/cas/config]. Changes require manual reloads/restarts.>
2018-08-30 13:19:37,111 WARN [org.apereo.cas.config.support.authentication.AcceptUsersAuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfiguration] - <>
2018-08-30 13:19:37,128 WARN [org.apereo.cas.config.support.authentication.AcceptUsersAuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfiguration] - <

  ____    _____    ___    ____    _
 / ___|  |_   _|  / _ \  |  _ \  | |
 \___ \    | |   | | | | | |_) | | |
  ___) |   | |   | |_| | |  __/  |_|
 |____/    |_|    \___/  |_|     (_)


CAS is configured to accept a static list of credentials for authentication. While this is generally useful for demo purposes, it is STRONGLY recommended that you DISABLE this authentication method (by setting 'cas.authn.accept.users' to a blank value) and switch to a mode that is more suitable for production.>
2018-08-30 13:19:37,129 WARN [org.apereo.cas.config.support.authentication.AcceptUsersAuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfiguration] - <>
2018-08-30 13:19:50,183 INFO [org.apereo.cas.support.events.listener.CasConfigurationEventListener] - <Refreshing CAS configuration. Stand by...>
2018-08-30 13:19:51,182 WARN [org.apereo.cas.config.CasCoreServicesConfiguration] - <Runtime memory is used as the persistence storage for retrieving and persisting service definitions. Changes that are made to service definitions during runtime WILL be LOST when the web server is restarted. Ideally for production, you need to choose a storage option (JDBC, etc) to store and track service definitions.>
2018-08-30 13:19:51,278 INFO [org.apereo.cas.services.AbstractServicesManager] - <Loaded [0] service(s) from [InMemoryServiceRegistry].>
2018-08-30 13:19:51,931 WARN [org.apereo.cas.util.cipher.BaseStringCipherExecutor] - <Secret key for encryption is not defined for [Ticket-granting Cookie]; CAS will attempt to auto-generate the encryption key>
2018-08-30 13:19:51,956 WARN [org.apereo.cas.util.cipher.BaseStringCipherExecutor] - <Generated encryption key [eTqXF8ggwLZtTQEZCskBylE0S4px3iBbGcverLvO2Fs] of size [256] for [Ticket-granting Cookie]. The generated key MUST be added to CAS settings under setting [cas.tgc.crypto.encryption.key].>
2018-08-30 13:19:51,961 WARN [org.apereo.cas.util.cipher.BaseStringCipherExecutor] - <Secret key for signing is not defined for [Ticket-granting Cookie]. CAS will attempt to auto-generate the signing key>
2018-08-30 13:19:51,973 WARN [org.apereo.cas.util.cipher.BaseStringCipherExecutor] - <Generated signing key [ZJNEO4PuSX3og9E923KKcp6bVVHb7bajkqkP1B4_35ytg4rW5CPqRvFYuxzmBTHAvsaTnBRvKqe53F_4ulg5Rw] of size [512] for [Ticket-granting Cookie]. The generated key MUST be added to CAS settings under setting [cas.tgc.crypto.signing.key].>
2018-08-30 13:19:53,293 WARN [org.apereo.cas.util.cipher.BaseBinaryCipherExecutor] - <Secret key for signing is not defined under [cas.webflow.crypto.signing.key]. CAS will attempt to auto-generate the signing key>
2018-08-30 13:19:53,295 WARN [org.apereo.cas.util.cipher.BaseBinaryCipherExecutor] - <Generated signing key [txKypaRUGM0NyMfI9reKAPzMCEuTDO4xWh9J-G16rmp5l-ZWpqBR7bge1wPvAx0FdYw2j__4aI_6Q9qANFe5ng] of size [512]. The generated key MUST be added to CAS settings under setting [cas.webflow.crypto.signing.key].>
2018-08-30 13:19:53,297 WARN [org.apereo.cas.util.cipher.BaseBinaryCipherExecutor] - <Secret key for encryption is not defined under [cas.webflow.crypto.encryption.key]. CAS will attempt to auto-generate the encryption key>
2018-08-30 13:19:53,300 WARN [org.apereo.cas.util.cipher.BaseBinaryCipherExecutor] - <Generated encryption key [xUiptRY2-RuCvAFV39UJlg] of size [16]. The generated key MUST be added to CAS settings under setting [cas.webflow.crypto.encryption.key].>
2018-08-30 13:19:53,867 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService] - <Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]>
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-catalina-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-catalina-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:265) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:208) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.CasWebApplication.main(CasWebApplication.java:71) ~[cas-server-webapp-init-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[cas.war:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[cas.war:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[cas.war:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) ~[cas.war:?]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1020) ~[tomcat-catalina-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-catalina-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No aliases for private keys found in key store
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:116) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-catalina-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-catalina-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No aliases for private keys found in key store
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:233) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:87) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-coyote-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-catalina-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-catalina-8.5.32.jar!/:8.5.32]
        ... 20 more
```

I also tried a different version with no luck.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 apereo/cas:v5.2.2
```

This appears to be a problem with missing keys that I (think) need to be generated but I'm not sure if/where I need to mount a volume or what to do next.

Comment: having the same problem with no luck debugging

Answer (score 5):

```
FILE: /etc/cas/config/
  keytool -genkeypair -alias cas -keyalg RSA \
     -keypass changeit -storepass changeit \
     -keystore $AP_HOME/etc/cas/thekeystore \
     -dname "CN=localhost.xxx.com.tw,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,C=TW" \
     -ext SAN="dns:localhost,ip:127.0.0.1,dns:`hostname`"
```

copy this file into container docker:

```
docker cp /etc/cas/thekeystore   *container_name*:/etc/cas
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to map the etc outside container, but maintains in container.

~/etc/cas/theKeystore
~/etc/cas/config/application.properties
~/etc/cas/config/cas.properties
~/etc/cas/config/log4j2.xml
~/cas-overlay: clone from github.

Try this
   docker --name ... 
   -p 8443:8443 -p ...
   -v ~/etc/cas:/etc/cas 
   -v ~/cas-overlay:/cas-overlay
 
   ...

I also maintain my project out of container.
such as modifing  ~/etc/cas/config/application.properties, ...
and/or rebuilding cas.war, in ~/cas-overlay/mvnm package.
then restart this container dokcer.